# Loading an address, as a symbol, into a general register

Tags: c, assembly, gnu-assembler, riscv

I have some RISC V assembly in a `crt.S` file.

If I use the name of the C function `_init` like this:

```
j _init
```

(i.e. execute an unconditional jump to `_init`), the code compiles fine and runs.

But if I use it like this:

```
li a3, _init
```

(ie, load general register `A3` with the integer value `_init`) the code will not compile. If I substitute a literal integer value (e.g., `0x80001958`, which all other things being equal, is value of `_init` currently) the code compiles.

What am I doing wrong here? (This is using GNU GCC/AS)

Comment: I ask a question about assembly syntax and somebody votes to close it because it's "not about programming"? No wonder people say this site is going to the dogs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RISC-V, but I am very familiar with other assembly languages.  Is the label `_init` local or external to your program?  I tried to find documentation on the `li` instruction, but couldn't find it explicitly defined in the RISC-V ISA manual.  What language reference book are you using to learn RISC-V?

Comment: The li is a pseudo instruction that leaves it to the assembler work out how to generate the right codes to build the number and then load it into the register (eg to do a shift plus add or just lad directly etc). It's very handy!
I've now worked out what the issue was after puzzling over it for hours - see the answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the 411.  For future reference you should post the assembler error that you received when using the `li` instruction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that - as RISCV supports a wide variety of address formats - I cannot use `li` and so work on the assumption that the address format is the same size as the register format. Instead, I have to use `la` to load a number appropriately extended to the address format as opposed to the integer register format.